# GitHub action fails with exit code 1 when command return 0

Tags: git, github-actions

I'm doing a github action for a project that has this part:

```yaml
 - name: Check for version change
        id: check_version
        run: |
          git fetch origin main
          VERSION_CHANGED=$(git diff --name-only ${{ github.event.before }}..HEAD | grep -c '^src/manifest.json$')
          echo "version_changed=$VERSION_CHANGED" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
```

It allows me to see if there has been a change in my manifest file. It returns 1 if yes and 0 if no.

The problem is that when it returns 1, all the rest of my action goes smoothly, but on the other hand, it exit me with this error:

```bash
Run git fetch origin main
  git fetch origin main
  VERSION_CHANGED=$(git diff --name-only 32f9a1bbdaa01bcda6cbc59973fe89707c92abc2..HEAD | grep -c '^src/manifest.json$')
  echo "version_changed=$VERSION_CHANGED" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
 * branch            main       -> FETCH_HEAD
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

And this is the result when everything goes well, even if I doubt it'll do any good:

```bash
Run git fetch origin main
  git fetch origin main
  VERSION_CHANGED=$(git diff --name-only c47cdb4394c93c367b97241d7618a7608e9acb64..HEAD | grep -c '^src/manifest.json$')
  echo "version_changed=$VERSION_CHANGED" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
 * branch            main       -> FETCH_HEAD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's relevant for the exit status is if grep matches something or not; the numeric value of `grep -c` doesn't matter directly.

If at least one line matches your regular expression, the exit status is 0 (success), and `VERSION_CHANGED` is 1 or more.

If no line matches, the exit status is 1 (not successful), and `VERSION_CHANGED` is 0 (if it is set at all, see below).

Because `run` steps have `set -e` enabled (exit on error), having no matches exits immediately and doesn't set `VERSION_CHANGED`.

Since you're not actually interested in the count of lines (I think), but just want to see if a specific file has been modified, you could move that check into an `if` condition, which is exempted from `set -e` behaviour:

```yaml
env:
  before: ${{ github.event.before }}
run: |
  if git diff --name-only "$before"..HEAD | grep -q '^src/manifest\.json$'; then
      changed=1
  else
      changed=0
  fi

  echo "VERSION_CHANGED=$changed" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
```

Instead of `grep -c`, I use `grep -q`, which sets the exit status only and doesn't produce any output.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very clear explanation. It works very well now!

Comment: sorry for the late return but I finally have another problem.
the $changed viarible returns nothing (I don't even think it's set).This is the output of my action:  `if git diff --name-only "$before"..HEAD | grep -q '^src/manifest\.json$'; then
      changed=1
  else
      changed=0
  fi
  echo "$changed"
  echo "version_changed=$changed" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"` and a test below `echo "version_changed="
  echo "version=1.0.41"` I can provide more details by editing my question if necessary.

Comment: @GuiEpi Depending on how you use `checkout`, you might have to use `fetch-depth: 0` in there, or else the checkout is shallow and fetches just `HEAD`. Or you might be able to run a separate job with a trigger for that file in [`paths`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpull_request_targetpathspaths-ignore).